# how to protect css files like this site

Tags: javascript, html, css, security

I use [this site](http://www.font-api.ir) for web font. (This is a web font provider like google fonts)
I need protect my css and js file like this site.

when you see below html file this css load complete and page show correctly but you don't access css files.

What method this site uses for securing css files??

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>B Koodak test</title>
        <link href='http://www.font-api.ir/css/B Koodak={font-api.ir}.css' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
        <style>
             .myclass{
             font-family:B Koodak,'B Koodak',tahoma;
             font-size:12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="myclass">This Is Test Text.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

for example if use access this link:

[http://www.font-api.ir/css/B Koodak={font-api.ir}.css](http://www.font-api.ir/css/B%20Koodak=%7Bfont-api.ir%7D.css)

this content is in base64 in above file: (thanks @Barmar and @Cracker0dks)

Rk9OVC1BUEkuaXI6DQpTYWxhbSENCnNoYXlhZCBsYXplbSBiYXNoYWQgYmVkYW5pZCBrZSBjb3B5
IGthcmRhbiBrYXJlIGtob29iaSBuaXN0IQ0KbG90ZmFuIGZvbnRlIG1vcmVkZSBuYXphcmUga2hv
ZCByYSBheiBmb250LWFwaS5pciBlbnRla2hhYiBrb25pZC4NCg==

This is decoded content. This is a message that say please no copy my css file (in persian language):

```
FONT-API.ir:
Salam!
shayad lazem bashad bedanid ke copy kardan kare khoobi nist!
lotfan fonte morede nazare khod ra az font-api.ir entekhab konid.
```

This is my chrome developer tools image:
[image: chrome developer tools image]

Network tab, Request header and response:
[image: chrome developer tools image network tab]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by protect? I easily accessed the reference site css, js files

Comment: It's not possible to both enable a user to *use* CSS *and* not access it at the same time. No access == no use.

Comment: Looks like it's just encoded as base64.

Comment: Thats no css in this base64. Decoded: FONT-API.ir:
Salam!
shayad lazem bashad bedanid ke copy kardan kare khoobi nist!
lotfan fonte morede nazare khod ra az font-api.ir entekhab konid.

Comment: I add example to question.

Comment: That site loads three CSS files. I can see them all like any other asset. Or do you mean there's a fourth file?

Comment: Try with [this](http://www.font-api.ir/css/B%20Koodak=%7Bfont-api.ir%7D.css) encoded url, it works.

Comment: What browser are you all using? I don't see any base64 code at all with Firefox, I get regular CSS that starts with `@font-face`?

Comment: I test with Firefox and Chrome and file content only a message no css style. (I add extra detail to question)

Comment: @RahilWazir how did you do that?? when I go to file from your link I see font-face.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I only see one css file that it is encode by base 64 and when I decode this coded content It's no css style and only a copy prevention message.

Comment: As afroze's answer explains, it's just a hot-linking countermeasure to prevent other sites from stealing your bandwidth. Your question suggests that you want to protect code from *your own* visitors, something that other site doesn't accomplish (or even try).

Comment: If It is hot-link protection why I can load from my local .html file?? And another deference: in hot-link protection purpose is saving bandwidth but this site protect css from copy and show a message that "please don't copy css and link to my css file". This site is a @font-face provider and want to protect css font from copy no for saving bandwidth.

Comment: Have you removed your browser's cache? Your screen-shot doesn't show the "Network" tab so there's no way to tell where the file comes from. And I can compose an error message that say "please shave your moustache" but my code will not really accomplish it :)

Comment: Yes I removed my browser cache and test again. I also add network tab image and request and response data. Please see question again.

Answer (score 5):

The site that you pointed out is using the HTTP "Referrer" header to protect its css files. However, it is very simple bypass this protection (e.g. by faking the http header or sniffing browser traffic). If you insist on applying the same kind of check on your side you have to do it through a configuration on your web server.

If you are using Apache web server you can do it via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Here is an online tool you can use to generate your htaccess for css files:
http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/

Comment: I think it is not referrer because when I copy Html to a .html file and open in browser my font-face is OK but again I don't access .css style content. I add image to my question.

Answer (score 0):

their css files are accessible. I know of no way to 'protect' since the browser downloads it.

follow these steps to view all css files:

1.in chrome, open dev tools (f12)

2.click cntr+o

1. enter '.css'

you now see all css files

EDIT in response to comment:

you are referring to just one part of the css: the @font-face import. by not usable, you mean that when you try to import this font, its not accessible? if so, they may be restricting responses to http requests to the url of the font: http://www.font-api.ir/fontsdir/35.eot?#'

the server at http://www.font-api.ir can filter its responses based on what domain is requesting the resource.

Comment: I add example to question. This css content is not usable.

Comment: No I don't see @font-face. I add image from my chrome developer tools.

Comment: please give me the name of the file that you wish to access, and I will try to show you how to read the contents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. for example [This](http://www.font-api.ir/css/B%20Yekan=%7Bfont-api.ir%7D.css) or [This](http://www.font-api.ir/css/B%20Nazanin=%7Bfont-api.ir%7D.css)

Comment: the files are accessible. The only content of each file is one @font-face  rule.  They are tiny css files to add one font. that's it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45278/discussion-between-codetoad-and-babak-haj-azim-zanjani)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally...it is not possible to protect `images`, `css` `js` or anything because when the browser loads a website, then *it has* to load all these elements too.....and if the browser is able to load it then any one can see/download the assets of the site.

Only possible things is to fake the stuffs for world using `.htaccess` write.

As for the site you referenced, the are using `http.setRequestHeader` to simply fool you....nothing is concrete...if you want to still access their stuffs, just do a little bit of googling and you'll yourself understand the difference!! :)

Answer (score -3):

They Using .htaccess file to hide or secure file / directory. HTACCESS is a powerful file that can manipulate user control even access right.

Comment: ...which would prevent the browser from downloading and applying the styles. You could also just not upload the css file to the server. :p

Comment: He ask for secuity for file . So many way to secure and prevent file . This is only my Idea for effective securing. Its also depend on how you  code or manipulate condition in you .htaccess. Tell me if Im wrong.